# How to display page title in form field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'd like to display the page title in a form input field using plain javascript.

I've tried this but it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

```html
<input type="text" value="javascript:document.title;"/>
```

Also, how can I check if the input field is actually there and do nothing if so. I'd like to do this check to avoid JS errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it would not. `value` is never executed. Try this instead:

```html
<title>title text here</title>

<!-- ... -->

<input type="text" id="titleinput">
<script>
  var theInput = document.getElementById('titleinput')
  if (theInput) {
    theInput.value = document.title;
  }
</script>
```

EDIT: Shown how to test for existence of the input, and removed the arcane way of finding title since there is a better way. Although, in this case, you might know that you've created the input field, and take it as granted that it is there (your program should make an error if it's not, just like it should make an error if you delete a line from the code itself. I would only have such a check on HTML that I do not control. It might be a personal choice though, I know I don't do enough defensive programming.

EDIT2: jasonscript has a point, but I thought it would confuse the OP even more. If you want a best-practices answer though, you'd do some variety of this, to avoid global variables:

```
(function(theInput) {
  if (theInput) {
    theInput.value = document.title;
  }
})(document.getElementById('titleinput'));
```

Comment: Thanks!  I added a comment to the OP: Can you show how to check for the existence of the input field?

Comment: You can check existence input field like this `var theInput = document.getElementById('titleinput'); if(theInput.length > 0) { //Your code here };`

Comment: @ilovebali: That is incorrect. You can use that method if you have a `NodeList`, such as when you call `querySelectorAll` or `getElementsByTagName` (but `> 0` is redundant, `if (nodelist.length)` is sufficient, since `0` is falsy, all other `length` values are truthy). If you use `getElementById`, you are getting either a `Node` (truthy) or `null` (falsy), so what I wrote in the answer is correct; the result of `getElementById` should never have a `length` property unless a programmer puts it there.

Comment: This code should be wrapped in a function expression (IIFE) to avoid unnecessary global variables

Comment: @Amadan `getElementsByTagName` actually returns `HTMLCollection`, while `querySelectorAll` does return `NodeList`. And their biggest difference is `getElementsByTagName` gives you a dynamic collection, `querySelectorAll` gives you a static one. For example, using `querySelectorAll` you can delete items of the collection in iteration, but with `getElementsByTagName` it may be unexpected.

Comment: @LeoDeng: Thanks, that is correct. The point stays the same, you can't test for success of `getElementById` using `length`.

Comment: Yep, I was a little off topic :)

Answer (score 2):

value attribute is a string, it wouldn't execute if you place some JS in it.

You would set its value with JS after the input is ready in DOM:

```
<input type="text" value="">
<script>
    document.querySelector('input').value = document.title;
</script>
```

Whereas `querySelector` will give you the first `input` element in the DOM.

Specificly, you can pass any css selectors to the method, e.g. ID selector in following code. Please note different parameter `querySelector` is using:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="titleInput">
<script>
    document.querySelector('#titleInput').value = document.title;
</script>
```

More on `querySelector`, visit [selectors api spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

Comment: No explanation of how to use this - you need to include info on where to place this code.  It'll have to be in an event handling function tied to body load or document ready (if using jQuery), etc.  the real problem is setting something in value doesn't evaluate it as a javascript statment.

Comment: @4thSpace: It does, in fact, work. However, as lukevp says, it doesn't say where to put it for it to be effective.

Comment: Another problem is, unless the asker understands what `querySelector` does, it will indiscriminately apply the change to the first `input` in the document, not necessarily the one he wants :) Still... better.

Comment: @Amadan well, how about leave `querySelector` as a further study for the asker? Since he would notice it as you have pointed out :)

Comment: removed my downvote, thanks for the quick update, the answer is much better now.

Comment: From my experience, many people will just apply the solution, not analysing it for potential defects. He might, in fact, *not* notice it. Two weeks later, they add another `input`, and bam! it breaks, and the user has no clue why. I don't mind `querySelector`, it is an awesome method and everyone should know about it, and it's the reason why I originally upvoted you (showing different approach than my own), but it would be good if the warning was explicit.

Comment: @Amadan maybe, but SO is a place that devoted to teaches people why rather than how, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

**HTML**:

```
<title>awesome site</title>



<input type="text" id="textinput" value=""/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script>
var title = document.title;
var textinput = document.getElementById('textinput');
if (textinput) {
textinput.value = title;
}
</script>
```

---

**or shorter:**

```
<script>
document.getElementById('textinput').value = document.title;
</script>
```